# Apply De-Moivre's Theorem to compute $i^2$.

Tags: complex-numbers

> Apply De-Moivre's Theorem to compute $i^2$.

**My Attempt:**

Let, $0+i^2=x+iy=r(\cos (\theta) + i.\sin (\theta))$

But, how do I compare?

Comment: Start with $i=\cos\frac{\pi}{2}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{2}$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by Euler’s formula, we have: $$i = (\cos \frac{\pi}{2}+i \sin \frac{\pi}{2}) $$ By De-Moivre’s formula: $$i^2 = \, ?$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $i = (0,1)$. The multiplication rule $(a,b)(c,d)= (ac-bd, ad+bc)$ implies that $(0,1)(0,1)=(-1,0)$. Therefore $i^2 =-1$.